# How to remove existing markers and infobubbles from HERE maps

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I'm using the HERE maps API for my maps. I'm able to add a marker and infobubble whenever I click on a map. However, I want only the latest marker and infobuble on the map, and removed all the other ones. Below is my code which has all the markers and infobubble after I click on the map multiple times.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1533195059" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="map" style="height:550px;width:720px;"></div>

<script>
    //Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'devportal-demo-20180625',
  app_code: '9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ',
      useHTTPS: true
    });
    var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
      tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
      ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
    });

    //Step 2: initialize a map  - not specificing a location will give a whole world view.
    var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      defaultLayers.normal.map, {pixelRatio: pixelRatio});

    //Step 3: make the map interactive
    // MapEvents enables the event system
    // Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

    // Create the default UI components
    var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers); 




function setUpClickListener(map) {
  map.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
    var coord = map.screenToGeo(evt.currentPointer.viewportX,
            evt.currentPointer.viewportY);
     addMarker(coord);
  });
}

function addMarker(coordinates){
    var marker = new H.map.Marker({lat:coordinates.lat, lng: coordinates.lng});
    map.addObject(marker);

    var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble({lat:coordinates.lat, lng: coordinates.lng}, {
            content: '<b>Hello World!</b>'
           });
    // show info bubble
    ui.addBubble(bubble);
}

setUpClickListener(map);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
map.removeObjects(map.getObjects ())
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call the [removeObject()](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-group.html#h-map-group__removeobject) method on the map or groups to remove map objects such as markers.

If you want to quickly remove all objects from the map, the easiest way to do this is to add them to a group and adding that group to the map. You can then call [removeAll()](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-group.html#h-map-group__removeall) on the group.

Comment: The removeObject I believe removes only a single item. I want to remove all the existing objects. I found a method map.removeObjects(searchMarkers), but I'm not sure how to apply it in my code.

Comment: I believe the easiest way to achieve this is to add all objects to a group before adding them to a map and then calling removeAll() on the group.

Answer (score 0):

First answer is totally fine, but what else is sometimes needed (e.g. u've got **2 totally separate objects** on the map, and you want to **delete all the objects of the first type, but left the second type**), then you cannot do:

`map.removeObjects(map.getObjects ())`, because it will **delete also objects from the second type**. So what works for me, was just to (it's in TS, so **`this` means global variable, not local!** :

```
map.addObject(myObject);
this.myLastObject = myObject;
```

or for `array/list`:

```
map.addObject(myObject);
this.myList.push(myObject);
```

and later deletion:

```
map.removeObject(this.myLastObject);
```

or do a loop for list or use `.removeObjects(this.myList)`